# How to start a python script after etcd is running in a single docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, etcd

I have built a docker file composed by python2.7-alpine and etcd (https://hub.docker.com/r/elcolio/etcd/), I'm trying to run a python script right after the etcd is running (from the same container), however I get connection error because the etcd has not up yet. Any suggestions? (I tried to make another CMD after last CMD and also to put the exec command into the run.sh)

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

RUN pip install python-etcd

# Create script directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./scripts /usr/src/app

## install etcd

RUN         apk add --update ca-certificates openssl tar && \
            wget https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases/download/v2.0.10/etcd-v2.0.10-linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
            tar xzvf etcd-v2.0.10-linux-amd64.tar.gz && \
            mv etcd-v2.0.10-linux-amd64/etcd* /bin/ && \
            apk del --purge tar openssl && \
            rm -Rf etcd-v2.0.10-linux-amd64* /var/cache/apk/*
VOLUME      /data
EXPOSE      2379 2380 4001 7001
ADD         run.sh /bin/run.sh
CMD  ["/bin/run.sh"]
```

> 2017-03-19T14:47:20.291046586Z etcd.EtcdConnectionFailed: Connection
>   to etcd failed due to
>   MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=2379): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /v2/keys/mq/username (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused',))",)

Comment: If the error is because `etcd` hasn't started up yet, you could using the bash `sleep` command to block until `etcd` has started.

Comment: thanks @Jakub, how can I know that the etcd is started?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am not familiar with `etcd`. Sorry. You could time how long it takes `etcd` to start up and sleep for a little more than that. If `etcd` has a function to "ping" it, you could try using that too. I.e., run the script if the ping indicates that `etcd` is running